# Gas limit error on Ropsten

Tags: ropsten

Is anyone experiencing gas limit/gas estimation errors while deploying to Ropsten?

Its faucet is not working now too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.